# calling web service through java script in mvc3

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-3

I made one web service, and try to call it with Java script, I found error of unknown method "ServiceImage".
This is the following code snap of JScipt

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    ServiceImage.GetImageContract(Txt, imageName, function (imgbol) {if (imgbol == true) ......    
</script>
```

`
I am using the following code also

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" >
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the error. Also, more code would be helpful, because with just what you have given us, we have NO idea about what else is going on.

Answer (score 1):

With ASP.NET MVC its probably easiest and arguably preferred to call a web service with jQuery like this:

(no paramerers passed or REST based web service)

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

(with parameters)

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(data) {
   $('.result').html(data);
   alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Here's more information on jQuery ajax API [jQuery Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)